# Hive:Create table.....like...stored as orc not working in sqlcontext

Tags: hiveql, apache-spark-dataset

```
create table new_temp like temp stored as orc
```

Above query working on Hive Console.

```
sqlContext.sql("create table new_temp like temp stored as orc");
```

Gives error.

Comment: add the error message

Comment: Failure Reason: 
mismatched input 'STORED' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 85)
== SQL ==
create table new_temp like temp  STORED AS ORC -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

Comment: Any solution to this. its not working in spark 2.1.0 as well same error I got...

Comment: Hi Ram, I tried a lot but didn't get this working. Also no reply from any community.